# How to flush a buffered log4j FileAppender without shutdown?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need to immediately flush the log to disk and then turn it into normal buffer mode.

The requirement is I need to generate hourly log. For example, user_info.2017-09-08-18.log. Every hourly will generate one. So I use a ScheduledExecutorService to write a simple string to log at the beginning of each hour. But i found that if the buffer is not full, the log is still in buffer. So I want to immediately write one log at the beginning of each hour, make sure every hour has a log. So Logger.shutdown() is not a proper method in this situation.

This is my properties definition:

```
log4j.appender.user_push_info=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.user_info.File=/data/log/user_info
log4j.appender.user_info.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH'.log'
log4j.appender.user_info.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.user_info.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.user_info.BufferedIO=true
log4j.appender.user_info.BufferSize=8192
```

Comment: Although the dupe is about "on shutdown", there *are* answers that are independent of shutdown or not.

Answer (score 1):

For Log4j 1.2, you can [set immediate flush](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.html) then come back to normal behavior with:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
Appender appender = logger.getAppender("name");
if ( appender instanceof WriterAppender ) {
     ( (WriterAppender) appender ).setImmediateFlush(true);
     logger.info("Flushing log");
     ( (WriterAppender) appender ).setImmediateFlush(false);
}
```

Comment: How to get fileAppender? i can get Appender using Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("name"), but there is no method called setImmediateFlush.

Comment: Which version of log4j are you using?

Comment: compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'.  It seems i should get FileAppender instead of Appender